# Subclassed UITableViewCell Creates Zombie Unless Retained

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nszombie

I've created a UITAbleViewCell subclass with a custom nib, and am using it in two different UITableViews in my app.  It works perfectly in one of the tables, but the other table crashes when I scroll it vigorously.  Instruments identifies a zombie in this code (in cellForRowAtIndexPath):

```
NSString *identifier = @"edit";
LogTableCell *cell = (LogTableCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

if (!cell) {
   cell = (LogTableCell*) [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LogTableCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];        
   [cell retain];       // prevents zombies!
}
NSLog(@"%@: retainCount: %d", identifier, [cell retainCount]);

// some other cell init stuff

return cell;
```

Notice the [cell retain]; line - when it's in there, the code works swimmingly.  Take it out, and crash.  NSLog always reports a retainCount of 2, so it shouldn't be necessary.  But if I do something like this:

```
   if ([cell retainCount] < 1) { [cell retain]; }       // does not prevent zombies!
```

it doesn't work.  There's no alloc/init, so I shouldn't have to do an autorelease or worry about this at all, and I've always thought that cellForRowAtIndexPath releases the cell for me.

When I'm not using Instruments, here's the error I get from xcode:

```
*** -[CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4d8e930
```

Even though it works with the [cell retain]; line, it looks like a leak to Analyze (and to me), so I'd like to resolve the problem.  Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: I figured it out with a little sleuthing.  The problem was happening in the sublcassed UITableViewCell's dealloc.  I had a handful of instance variables, and a handful of properties, all of which I was releasing in dealloc.  But some of the properties were @synthesized to some of those instance variables, and when they're paired up that way, they collectively only need to be released once.  So I commented out the instance variable releases that were tied to properties, and it fixed the problem.  I hope this helps somebody!

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid using properties in your dealloc method. A property call can have unwanted side-effects. Releasing your ivar avoids any potential issues.

Comment: It isn't a huge issue, lots of people release variables via properties and Apple even does it in some of their example code... but all things being equal, directly access the iVar.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!  When you say "using properties in your dealloc method," do you mean "releasing properties in your dealloc method?"

Comment: I mean saying: `self.property = nil;` instead of `[property release];`

Answer (score 2):

## Do not call retainCount

The absolute retain count is useless.

`([cell retainCount] < 1)` cannot possibly work;  `retainCount` can never return zero.

(Yup -- loading a nib in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is now blessed by the framework. Coolio.)

Your problem, then, lies elsewhere as that code (without the retain) is correct.

It is still quite likely to be an autorelease pool drain that is happening before the regular event loop drain.   In particular, something somewhere has a weak reference to the cell that shouldn't.

If you fire up the Allocations Instrument and turn on retain/release event recording, you can see exactly where the calls to retain/release/autorelease the object occur.   The event that causes the crash is of obvious value.

In this case, though, you are probably missing a retain/release pair somewhere.  At least, that would be a fix for the symptoms.  The real problem is likely some kind of UI transition that happens such that some contents are effectively prematurely reaped while some other section of your app still has dependencies on it.   Adding a retain/release pair such that the lifespan of the cell is preserved across that transition isn't really a fix in that there may be other dependencies.

Comment: There shouldn't be any performance problems with doing the custom `UITableViewCell` this way. I've done something almost identical with no performance penalties and this is very close to [Apple's recommendation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20).

Comment: I've done this before, and I haven't seen any performance problems whatsover.  Also, I assumed that retainCount could never return zero, but I figured it was worth a try.